# How to solve a puzzle with numerals

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Any insights are welcome for this puzzle.

> The following equation is wrong: $103 - 102 = 3$. Move one numeral to make it correct. The numeral moved is: $0,1,2$ or $3$?

Comment: Can you move the same number from both $102$ and $103$?If you can, you get the equation $13-12=(3^0)^0$

Comment: It's not a trick solution is it? - move one of the $1$s on top of the equals sign to make it look like $\ne$?

Comment: @David I have always tried such a solution in similar puzzles but it was never correct...I think it should be an equation which will be correct.

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas it was the wording that made me suspicious - it doesn't actually say "move one numeral to make a correct equation". . .

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas: All conditions I know of are in the formulation, so I have no idea whether it shall be just a single move or we can move the same numeral. I think, with a single one nothing works so anyways it is worth trying with two. I was not sure whether additional operations are permitted though: that is, can we find a solution of the form $x - y = z$ with no more operations?

Comment: @David I've had the same puzzle but it didn't specify "numeral" and there was no follow-up question. Naturally I changed it to 103102 ≠ 3

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Konstantinos was on the right track.

> $$103 - 10^2 = 3$$

Since the question was "how to solve it", for any interested...

I solved it by first seeing that all the obvious a + b = c can be eliminated by seeing the range of the reduced or increased numbers.  Konst suggested exponents, which is the only other operator I can think of, $1$ is too small to be helpful, but 2 or 3 could work.

Comment: I thought it would be the 2.  To say that the numeral was 0, 1, or 3 would have been vague because there were two copies of each.

Comment: Thanks, but the same question here as to @Konstantinos: I am not sure whether additional operations are allowed. Is there a solution of the form $x - y = z$ where $x,y,z$ are just simple digital expressions ($102$ is simple, $10^2$ is not)?

Comment: @S.D. No, you can see that by reducing any number from 103 you get a negative difference, reducing any number from 102 gets a difference in excess of 80 (which the 3 can't create), and removal from 3 doesn't leave any valid grammatical expression behind.  Therefore there must be some interpretation necessary.

Comment: @DanielV: thanks, I had similar arguments - but just thought I overlooked some thing.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution: use Roman numerals:

```
CIII - CII = III
         ^
         move this one

CIIII - CI = III
    ^
    to here
```

(or

```
CIII - CII = III
               ^
               move this one

CIIII - CII = II
    ^
    to here
```

)

Comment: Although that is unlikely to help if you want to pass the test, thanks for idea.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the digit $2$ upward to the superscript position, so that it appears as an exponent of $10$ without adding an operator symbol.

Comment: How does that differ from the answer of DanielV?

Comment: Maybe they got confused by the hidden spoiler field

Answer (score -1):

The solution indeed uses exponents:

$103-10^2=3$

Comment: How does that differ from the answer of DanielV?